# How to fetch a embed and have it posted in another channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a report feature for my Discord Bot. Currently if a user types in
%report (user name) (rule # broken) (details). The bot creates a pending report in a staff chat as a embed. I want a staff member to have the ability to use a command to fetch the embed by its ID, and have it sent to a another discord channel for further review. Currently I cant think of any ideas to achieve this result and im wondering if anyone here can point me in the right direction.

I was going to have the command work like this, %review (message ID).
This would fetch the message currently in the staff chat and have it sent to a higher authority for further review.

P.S My code isnt organized to well and I apologize for that. I will try answering any questions you may have so I can clear up the confusion.

```
 bot.on("message", async message => {

if(message.author.bot) return;

if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'report'){
        console.log((message.author.username)+ ' is trying to create a report');
            let username = args[0]
            let rule = args[1]
            let notes = args.splice(2).join(" ")
            const report = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle("Pending Report")
            .setFooter("UMA Report")
            .addField('username: ', username)
            .addField('Rule Broken: ', rule)
            .addField('Notes: ', notes)
            .addField('Report Set By: ', "<@" + message.author.id + ">")
            .setTimestamp()
            bot.channels.cache.get('53453453345').send({ embed: report })
            console.log((message.author.username)+ ' has created a report on: '+ username);
            
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the message from the staff channel and resend it to another channel.

```js
} else if (command === 'review') {
  let ID = args[0];
  const embedMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch(ID);
  const embed = embedMessage.embeds[0];
  (await bot.channels.fetch(/* other channel ID */)).send(embedMessage.content, { embed });
}
```

**References:**

- [`Message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel)
- [`TextChannel.messages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages)
- [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)
- [`Channel.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds)
- [`Client.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels)
- [`ChannelManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)
- [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Your solution managed to retrieve regular messages which worked perfectly. Unfortunately, whenever the bot is trying to fetch an embed it comes back with a console error stating that the message content is empty. What I understand from this is that embeds are not fetched within the code. I still want to thank you however as this has pointed me in the right direction on this project.

Comment: @TheTecno I have modified the code, so that it hopefully will work with embeds. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Thank you so much! The edit worked like a charm. The embed has all the data that was supplied to it and was sent to the channel specified. Thanks again, ive been trying to figure this out for a while.